# UIToolBar button image

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using following code for add  button with image on tool bar, but it is only showing color no image is displaying.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *locationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butImg.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(butImgPressed:)];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure `[UIImage imageNamed:@"butImg.png"]` isn't nil.

Comment: image is not nil, it is showing white color on place of image yuji, Thanks yuji & Parth.

Comment: A workaround you can probably think off is to make a button with this image and add the button as a custom view to the bar button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way to do it:

```
UIButton *btnName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btnName setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 21)];

[btnName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butImg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[btnName addTarget:self action:@selector(butImgPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *locationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnName];
```

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, I have done the same , i want to know why image is not showing with this code                            UIBarButtonItem *locationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butImg.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(butImgPressed:)];

Answer (score 4):

You want to know why it doesn't work?

The reason `UIToolBar` was creating the white mask, was because the `UIToolBar` doesn't allow color images on it by default.

So the only way to accomplish what You want is by using `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIButton` as customView.